# Expression results in the default case when called directly from object versus passed in as a parameter

Tags: java, json, libgdx, switch-statement

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this switch statement behaves the way it does and can't seem to find an answer.

I have a Games class with two static create methods:

```
public final class Games {
public static final int THIRTEEN = 1;
public static final int HEARTS = 2;

public static CardGame create(final int gameId, final GameConnection connection, 
                              final GameSettings settings, List<Card> cards) {
    switch(gameId) {
        case THIRTEEN:
            return new ThirteenCardGame(connection, (ThirteenGameSettings) settings, cards);
        case HEARTS:
            return new HeartsCardGame(connection, (HeartsGameSettings) settings, cards);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

public static CardGame create(final Deal deal, final GameConnection connection, 
                              final GameSettings settings) {
    switch(deal.getGameId()) {
        case THIRTEEN:
            ThirteenDeal thirteenDeal = (ThirteenDeal)deal;
            return new ThirteenCardGame(connection, (ThirteenGameSettings) settings, thirteenDeal.getCards());
        case HEARTS:
            return new HeartsCardGame(connection, (HeartsGameSettings) settings, deal.getCards());
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
}
```

In the first method, gameId equals 1 and is passed in by deal.getGameId() from the caller. The switch statement evaluates to case THIRTEEN as I would expect.

Now when I call the second method passing in the Deal object entirely, the switch statement evaluates to the default case even though deal.getGameId() == 1.

Furthermore, if I change the method signature to maybe obtain the expression value from the caller, then pass in the Deal object:

```
public static CardGame create(final int gameId, final GameConnection connection, 
                              final GameSettings settings, Deal deal) {
    switch(gameId) {
        case THIRTEEN:
            return new ThirteenCardGame(connection, (ThirteenGameSettings) settings, cards);
        case HEARTS:
            return new HeartsCardGame(connection, (HeartsGameSettings) settings, cards);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

I get the same result as the second method (default case). Can someone tell me what is happening?

I should also point out that prior to the call, the Deal object is serialized using the Libgdx serializer like so:

```
mJson = json.toJson(object);
```

and deserialized the same way:

```
Json json = new Json();
return json.fromJson(Deal.class, serializedObjectString);
```

Although I have checked and verified the value of `Deal.getGameId()` is the value it was before it was serialized which was `1`.

Comment: Show the getGameId() method and the code that calls the second version.

Comment: When in doubt, print it out. See what `Deal#getGameId` is actually returning right before the switch statement.

Comment: `Deal.getGameId()` is just a simple getter that returns a member variable set by an equally simple setter. I have printed it out and it returns `1` every time.

Comment: Something is not as you think. Print the value you're switching in immediately before the switch statement in each case. But this a poor object model. The Game should create the Deal, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

`ThirteenDeal.getGameId()` and `HeartsDeal.getGameId()` are not returning 1 and 2 respectively.

The code doesn't have any other problem wrt switch-case. The switch-case functionality works fine.

### EDIT:

**Code**

```
import java.util.List;

public final class Games {
    public static final int THIRTEEN = 1;
    public static final int HEARTS = 2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        create(1, null, null, null);
        create(2, null, null, null);
        create(new ThirteenDeal(), null, null);
        create(new HeartsDeal(), null, null);
        create(-1, null, null, null);
        create(new Deal(), null, null);
    }
    public static CardGame create(final int gameId,
            final GameConnection connection, final GameSettings settings,
            List<Card> cards) {
        switch (gameId) {
        case THIRTEEN:
            System.out.println("Method Type 1, GameId=[" + gameId + "] - THIRTEEN");
            return new ThirteenCardGame(connection,
                    (ThirteenGameSettings) settings, cards);
        case HEARTS:
            System.out.println("Method Type 1, GameId=[" + gameId + "] - HEARTS");
            return new HeartsCardGame(connection,
                    (HeartsGameSettings) settings, cards);
        default:
            System.out.println("Method Type 1, GameId=[" + gameId + "] - (DEFAULT)");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static CardGame create(final Deal deal,
            final GameConnection connection, final GameSettings settings) {
        switch (deal.getGameId()) {
        case THIRTEEN:
            System.out.println("Method Type 2, GameId=[" + deal.getGameId() + "] - THIRTEEN");
            ThirteenDeal thirteenDeal = (ThirteenDeal) deal;
            return new ThirteenCardGame(connection,
                    (ThirteenGameSettings) settings, thirteenDeal.getCards());
        case HEARTS:
            System.out.println("Method Type 2, GameId=[" + deal.getGameId() + "] - HEARTS");
            return new HeartsCardGame(connection,
                    (HeartsGameSettings) settings, deal.getCards());
        default:
            System.out.println("Method Type 2, GameId=[" + deal.getGameId() + "] - (DEFAULT)");
            return null;
        }
    }
    /*
     * Deal Objects. Deal returns -1, ThirteenDeal returns 1 and HeartsDeal returns 2 
     */
    private static class Deal {
        public int getGameId() {
            return -1;
        }
        public Object getCards() {
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static class ThirteenDeal extends Deal {
        public List<Card> getCards() {
            return null;
        }
        public int getGameId() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    private static class HeartsDeal extends Deal {
        public List<Card> getCards() {
            return null;
        }
        public int getGameId() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    /*
     * Dummy stubs for the sake of compilation
     */
    private static class CardGame {
    }
    private static class Card {
    }
    private static class GameConnection {
    }
    private static class ThirteenGameSettings extends GameSettings {
    }
    private static class HeartsGameSettings extends GameSettings {
    }
    private static class ThirteenCardGame extends CardGame {
        public ThirteenCardGame(GameConnection connection,
                ThirteenGameSettings settings, List<Card> cards) {
        }
    }
    private static class HeartsCardGame extends CardGame {
        public HeartsCardGame(GameConnection connection,
                HeartsGameSettings settings, Object cards) {
        }
    }
    private static class GameSettings {
    }
}
```

And the output is,

```
Method Type 1, GameId=[1] - THIRTEEN
Method Type 1, GameId=[2] - HEARTS
Method Type 2, GameId=[1] - THIRTEEN
Method Type 2, GameId=[2] - HEARTS
Method Type 1, GameId=[-1] - (DEFAULT)
Method Type 2, GameId=[-1] - (DEFAULT)
```

If the Deal.getGameId() is evaluated to 1, there is no way it can go to `default`. As other have also suggested, please print the value just before the switch clause. If you suspect, that value could be altered in another thread, then, get the `deal.getGameId()` in a local variable and use that in switch class.

If nothing works, alter your below code in the second method, 
`switch(deal.getGameId()) {`
to

```
int gameId = deal.getGameId();
System.out.println("deal.getGameId()=" + gameId);
switch(gameId) {
```

and, check the output.

Comment: Admittedly I haven't tried the `HeartsDeal.getGameId()` case but it should not have any bearing on the `ThirteenDeal.getGameId()` case.

Comment: Okay, I will update with code, what I mean by that. You can check the construct, and the output to see the problem.